# Android onDraw delay by X seconds with handler makes UI sluggish

Tags: android, handler

I've been scratching my head on this one for a while and would appreciate any help on the matter (quite new to Android and Java so I'm guessing there's an easy one for this):

I'm creating a view which is meant to simulate a drawing for the user (it is going to be one of his previous drawings, so there's going to be a lot of timedeltas to take into account between points). Initially I tried thread.sleep, but obviously this got my UI going berserk. Following suggestions by similar posts I tried async tasks and handlers and so far the only thing I got working is the handler below. It does the job, but the UI is very sluggish (button clicks are quite slow to respond), which probably means it would get much worse when simulating someone's full drawing.

Any help would be much appreciated :)
Thanks!

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        drawPath.moveTo(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.canvas = canvas;
        canvas.save();

        drawPath.lineTo(200, 200);
        drawPath.lineTo(220, 240);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {                    
                drawPath.lineTo(250, 260);
            }
        }, 2000);
        invalidate();
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);

    }
```

Comment: Create `Handler` as member of your class. And maybe only access it outside of `onDraw()` and operate on a preset data set.

Comment: It seems that it it only works initially, but after a while the UI gets sluggish again :/ I'm guessing it's because I'm calling invalidate() at the bottom, which, if I understood correctly, calls onDraw() again.

Comment: Indeed, that's really not good. Try to abstract the dataset you'd like to draw and modify this one. Then call invalidate after this modification. You should do as little as possible in `onDraw()` and consider that it can be called outside of your animation scope as well.